# Prevent Classic ASP from encoding special characters in cookies

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

As a stop-gap, we are using CloudFlare to handle mobile redirection for a number of our much older sites that are still running Classic ASP. In order to bypass mobile redirection for pages which we don't have a mobile version of, CloudFlare requires we set the following cookie:

__cf_mob_redir

The issue here is that Classic ASP is turning that into this:

%5F%5Fcf%5Fmob%5Fredir

Which if we controlled the reading of the cookie wouldn't matter, but we don't, so it's an issue.

My question is: How can I set a cookie value that includes an underscore in classic ASP?

Comment: That looks like it's URL Encoded. How are you sending the value of the cookie - is it through a querystring.  Anyway, here's a link to an asp URL Decode function - http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp

Comment: If we were the ones reading the cookie, then yes that would help. The issue isn't reading the cookie, but setting the cookie. We have to be able to set the cookie without the character encoding.

Comment: You need to show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

This pure ASP only line worked for me.

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "__cf_mob_redir=__cf_mob_redir; HttpOnly"
```

Ignore previous answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this requires the page be returned before being able to set the cookie and send a header response, which in this case would be a 301/302 redirect.

Comment: @Greg-J You're not being very clear. If you want to receive the correct help post some code so people don't have to second guess.

Comment: There is no way for me to be more clear. I need to set a cookie with an underscore in the name that is not encoded using Classic ASP. Your solution uses JavaScript that happens to be written to the browser window using ASP.

Comment: @Greg-J I edited my answer giving a solution that I personally tried, and that works fine on a production server, that use only classic ASP, that let you send the header response without returning the page, exactly as you specified in your comment. 
Let us now if doesn't work because the problem in that case is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The "httpOnly option" forbids any JavaScript access to the cookie. We can’t see such a cookie or manipulate it using document.cookie.

This work:

```
response.write "<script type=""text/javascript"">"
response.write "document.cookie = ""cookie_name=cookie value; expires=Thu, 25 Dec 2023 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"";"
response.write "</script>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps, but here is a solution that should set a cookie with Javascript from Classic ASP (VB Script).

```
response.write "<script type=""text/javascript"">"
response.write "set_cookie('cookie_name', " & cookie_value & ");"
response.write "</script>"
```